# How to generate dummy anonymous class in Laravel factory

Tags: php, laravel, factory, faker

I want to generate some dummy anonymous class data, However, it seems that the  factory::define method only accept Class, I have tried these, but still with no avail

```
$factory->define(stdClass::class, function($faker) {
    return [
        "hello" => "world"
    ];
});
```

or even

```
$factory->define("CUSTOMOBJECT", function($faker) {
    return [
        "hello" => "world"
    ];
});
```

so that I could generate something like this;

```
factory("CUSTOMOBJECT")->make() // generate some anonymous object with field hello and value world
```

Is there a way that I could do the same thing without any class definition but still in the Laravel's 'factory way'? Any solution or any other approach to hide complexities in making a dummy object is appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by anonymous object? For any specific model or else?

Comment: Just in case: `"world` is missing the closing `"`

Comment: @kerhbh0lz just a typo

Comment: Object that doesn't belong to specific class, like those create with (object) ['hello' => 'world'], the point is the factory definition only accept Class, is there a possibility to create one without any class? @Dev

Comment: But 99% of time, you use factories to save to the database, how would you combat that with anonymous classes?

Comment: A factory is supposed to be determinate and that would not follow that rule. Why are you trying to do this? Maybe we can help you find another way?

Comment: Working with some legacy code base here, I'm trying to hide the complexity in making the object (as well trying to seed its data with Faker), any other approach would be fine. @Savlon